# Shtooka no longer responding / Shtooka ne répond plus

Tags: discussion

This is just to let you know that [project Shtooka](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtooka) is apparently in a deep sleep.  There are some details on [Framagora](http://forum.framasoft.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=36521)

> - We've not succeeded in getting a response from the leader of the project and Shtooka seems to be in a deep sleep.
> - The great news is that two people (notably Eric, thanks to him) belonging to the project are in the process of getting the project back on track by recovering nearly all the work already done. <sub>[Cyrille@Framagora](http://forum.framasoft.org/viewtopic.php?p=285343&sid=8298a7692c7e23931892fbe4e1d6d1f8#p285343)</sub>

There are [several answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=shtooka) that talk about it, and as there's no replacement yet, I will definitely note on the links concerned that Shtooka is dead with a link to here.  I'll try to do what's necessary when something becomes available.  For people pressed for time, there is clearly a way of recovering some resources in [a repository still on the server](http://packs.shtooka.net/), or on [archive.org](http://archive.org).

---

Simplement pour vous signaler que le [projet Shtooka](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtooka) est apparemment en sommeil très profond. Il y a quelques détails sur [Framagora](http://forum.framasoft.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=36521)

> - Nous n'avons pas réussi à avoir de réponse de la personne qui dirigeait le projet et Shtooka semble en sommeil très profond.
> - La très bonne nouvelle, c'est que deux personnes (notamment Eric, merci à lui) appartenant au projet sont en train de se débrouiller pour remettre le projet en marche en récupérant quasiment tout le travail déjà réalisé. <sub>[Cyrille@Framagora](http://forum.framasoft.org/viewtopic.php?p=285343&sid=8298a7692c7e23931892fbe4e1d6d1f8#p285343)</sub>

Il y a [plusieurs réponses](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=shtooka) qui en parlent, comme il n'y a pas encore de remplacement, je vais surement noter sur les liens concernés que le lien est mort avec un lien vers ici. J'essaierais de faire le nécessaire quand quelque chose sera accessible. Pour les gens pressés il y a visiblement moyen de récupérer des ressources dans dans [un répertoire encore sur le serveur](http://packs.shtooka.net/) ou sur [archive.org](http://archive.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2013-05-26, [Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/) seems to have resurrected, it is up and working at http://shtooka.net/ though some links to specific sounds may or may not work as they did.